# Passing a form-data multivaluedmap parameter with SoapUI

Tags: java, rest, soapui

I'm trying to test a restful web-service with SoapUI which has the following signature:

```
@PUT
@Path("{addressId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response upload(@PathParam(PARAM_ADDRID) Long addressId,
                       @FormDataParam("header") MultivaluedMap<String, String> header,
                       @FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream) {...
```

I'm not able to pass the "header"-param correctly.
The "header"-param should not be sent into the header's request. That's why I defined that with the annotation @FormDataParam. This can't be changed.

[image]

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Is the header supposed to be a map?

Comment: i'm sorry for waiting so long to answer your question @AbhishekAsthana... yes the header is  as map... a MultivaluedMap to be specifc... still searching for a solution hier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleg of mine find out how to do that.
He has defined a testcase property which contains the header information packed as a key-value map. Then he passed this file to the request with content type of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

In other words... a MultivaluedMap formdata parameter is a property file with key-values entries!

[image]